# C - Passing a function value to another function

Tags: c

I have the following program that calls two functions, one to gather the sum of an array, one to gather the average:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float array_sum (float myNumbers[],int size)
{
    float sum = 0;
    int i; /* Variable used in loop counter */

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        sum +=myNumbers[i];
    }

}

float array_average (float myNumbers[],int size)
{
    float sum = 0;
    float average = 0;
    int i; /* Variable used in loop counter */

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        sum +=myNumbers[i];
    }

    average = sum/size;
    printf("avg = %5.2f", average);
}

int main (void)
{
    int size;
    int sum;

    printf ("Enter The Amount Of Numbers In Your Array: ");
    scanf("%i", &size);

    float myNumbers[size];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf ("Enter the number:");
        scanf (" %f",&myNumbers[i]);
    }

    array_sum(myNumbers,size);
    array_average(myNumbers,size);

    return 0; 
}
```

What I want to do is display both the `array_sum` and the `array_average` results at the end of my program. Furthermore, I think it would be more efficient to pass the `array_sum` through the `array_average` function instead of calculating for the array sum again? Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: You claim that `array_sum` and `array_average` return a float, but neither of those functions has a `return` statement. Perhaps you could return the value you want that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `printf` in your functions, you should return the value:

```
return sum;
```

or

```
return average;
```

Both your functions expect a `float` return value anyway.  Your compiler should have warned you about this.  Anyway, you should be able to call it like this (assuming you have the relevant variables declared in `main`):

```
sum = array_sum(myNumbers,size);
average = array_average(myNumbers,size);
printf("sum = %5.2f", sum);
printf("avg = %5.2f", average);
```

Obviously, the `array_average` function is doing a lot of the same work as `array_sum` without adding any additional value, so you should calculate the sum by calling `array_sum` instead of duplicating the code.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can *call* the sum function from the average function to make it do the work without repeating code. Second, you declare both functions with a return type, but you don't return anything. You need to add a return statement and then set the returned value to a variable in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best if your functions return the relevant value.  Neither of your worker functions has a return statement, which they should.  Your compiler should warn you about this; heed those warnings.

Secondly, your functions will be more reusable if they don't print the values themselves, as `array_average` currently does.  Putting this all together, modify your worker functions to return the value in question; then you can use code something like this:

```
float sum = array_sum(myNumbers, size);
printf("sum = %5.2f; avg = %5.2f", sum, sum/size);
```

It is also worth noting that your program may suffer from overflow and loss of precision.  However based on your problem I would say these issues should be taken up at a more advanced level of study.  Make sure to come back to them though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a feeling you are supposed to have those functions, by which one could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Pass pointer to a target variable where to save sum. 
 * Though it can be nice to return it, it all depends on usage.
 * Conventionally one often return status code, and edit params.
 */
int array_sum(float myNumbers[], int size, float *sum)
{
    int i;

    /* This would indicate you have asked for the sum of an empty set. */
    if (size < 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    *sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        *sum += myNumbers[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int array_average(float sum, unsigned int size, float *avg)
{
    /* Duh. */
    if (size == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    *avg = sum / size;
    return 0;
}


/* A lot of redundant checks here, but only to show the concept.
 * Normally one would often call the function from context where
 * one does not have control on e.g. "size" before you actually 
 * are going to sum it.
 *
 * Here you would probably check if size is < 1 after scanf and
 * ask for new number or abort.
 */
int main(void /* int argc, char *argv[] */)
{
    int i;
    int size;
    float sum;
    float avg;
    float *myNumbers;

    printf ("Enter The Amount Of Numbers In Your Array: ");
    if (!scanf("%i", &size)) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Unable to read size.\n"
        );
        return 1;
    }

    if ((myNumbers = malloc(sizeof(float)* size)) ==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Memory error.\n"
        );
        return 2;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Enter the number: ");
        if (!scanf("%f", &myNumbers[i])) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                "Unable to read float.\n"
                "Try again."
            );
            scanf("%*s"); /* Empty out buffer. */
            --i;          /* Reset count. */
        }
    }

    if (array_sum(myNumbers, size, &sum) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Sum failed.\n"
        );
        return 2;
    }

    if (array_average(sum, size, &avg) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "AVG failed.\n"
        );
        return 3;
    }

    fprintf(stdout,
        "Total numbers: %d\n"
        "Sum          : %.2f\n"
        "AVG          : %.2f\n"
        ,
        size,
        sum,
        avg
    );

    free(myNumbers);

    return 0;
}
```